# Calling vcvarsall.bat in Python and using its env variables

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, build

I am trying to replace an old batch script handling building a project with a python script. I am aware of the subprocess module, however I don't know how to call vcvarsall.bat, which sets environment variables necessary to compile our project, and continue entering commands. What I need is python code that runs these 3 commands in succession:

`cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64`

`qmake config+=somevars`

`nmake Somevars`

Simply calling vcvarsall.bat like this:

`subprocess.check_output(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat", "amd64"])`

doesn't set the environment variables in a way that they are accessible to the follow up commands.

I am in a Windows10 based docker container and Python3.6

Comment: It is likely that `CALL` needs to be used for the vcvarsall.bat file. Also, this cannot be three (3) separate subprocesses. When a subprocess ends, the environment it create also disappears.

Comment: so how do I do that correctly in python?

Comment: Create a batch file that 1) CALL vcvarsall.bat amd64, 2) qmake config+=somevars, and 3) nmake Somevars. If qmake and nmake were .bat files, CALL would need to be used for them as well.

Comment: oh ok. I hoped there would be a nice simple python way to do it. I'll give it a try tomorrow and report the results.

Comment: If you want to keep it all in Python, you could have the Python code write the .bat file in the TEMP directory, run the .bat file, then delete the .bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it as suggested by @lit using a 3 line .bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
qmake config+=somevars
nmake Somevars
```

and calling that using `Popen().wait()`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)